# What's the right way for handling Async functions for loading a .gif image?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, ecmascript-2017

For example, look at this code:

```js
function myPromise() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('Stack Overflow');
        }, 2000);
    });
}
async function sayHello() {
     const externalFetchedText = await myPromise();
     console.log('Hello ' + externalFetchedText);
}

sayHello();
```

What's the right way for showing a (.gif image file) loading before the request and hide this after Promise is resolved and the process is finished?

Comment: FYI, can also just do `setTimeout(resolve, 2000, 'Stack Overflow')`. I realize that's not the focus here, just saying you can do that.

Answer (score 9):

Most of time `promises` are abstracted into seprated module and are independent. So you should never do any other operation than `async` operation in the promises. You can show your `gif` while resolving the promises. See below code to show animation after you make `async` call, and hide it after resolution. You also have to handle `reject` scenario via `try/catch/finally` block.

```js
function myPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve('Stack Overflow');
            // reject('Some Error')
        }, 2000);
    });
}

function showSpinner() {
  document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'block';
}

function hideSpinner() {
  document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
}

async function sayHello() {
     try {
       showSpinner()
       const externalFetchedText = await myPromise();
       console.log('Hello ' + externalFetchedText);
     } catch (err) {
       console.error(err);
     } finally {
       hideSpinner()
     }
}

sayHello();
```

```html
<img id="loader" style="display:none" src="http://chimplyimage.appspot.com/images/samples/classic-spinner/animatedCircle.gif" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the promise if you want all the calling code that uses this promise to display the loading animation.

```
function myPromise() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        // Show image
        setTimeout(() => {
            // Hide image
            resolve('Stack Overflow');
        }, 2000);
    });
}
async function sayHello() {
    const externalFetchedText = await myPromise();
    console.log('Hello ' + externalFetchedText);
}

sayHello();
```

Comment: There's not really a good argument for tightly coupling loading animation toggling with resource fetching like this. I much prefer [@VipinKumar's take](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47808051/1541563) on considering separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myPromise() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            //resolve('Stack Overflow');
            reject('hello world');
        }, 2000);
    });
}
const newPromise = myPromise().then(result => {
   "hide here"
   return result;
}).catch(error => {
 "hide here"
  return error
});
async function sayHello() {
     const externalFetchedText = await newPromise;
     console.log('Hello ' + externalFetchedText);
}

sayHello();
```